# Attempt to index global 'Grid' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I have been trying to run the following codes from [Euler Equations Solver](http://ammar-hakim.org/sj/sims/s5/s5-euler-shock-wave.html). It is a Lua script that I have been toying with using ZeroBrane Studio. But the project gave the following error every time I try to execute it.

> attempt to index global 'Grid' (a nil value)
>
> stack traceback:
>
> ...mming Codes\Project 1\Lua Script\Problem 1\Problem 1.lua:7: in main chunk
>       [C]: at 0x00401b00

I am completely new to Lua and I have been looking for the solutions everywhere. Appreciate any help that I can get.

Comment: I am assuming you need to include a library for the solver to your script using the `require` statement

Comment: The code is designed to be run only under [specific environment](https://github.com/ammarhakim/gkyl) (a modified version of LuaJIT with additional libraries included).  It's impossible to run it under stock Lua.